# How to make an class object that passes arguments to a class visible to other methods

Tags: c#

I'm working in visual studio and the assignment is to create a class named car with a constructor that accepts arguments.  My problem is that since it accepts the arguments and I need to get the information from the user to pass it, I'm not sure how to make the class object seen by all methods.  I tried passing to a method to get the object but I'm obviously doing something wrong because I'm getting an error which i'll comment on below.  Any help would be great.

This is my class

```
class Car
{
    //fields for the Car class
    private string _year;
    private string _make;
    private int _speed;

    //constructor
    public Car(string year, string make)
    {
        _year = year;
        _make = make;
        _speed = 0;
    }

    //Year property
    public string Year
    {
        get { return _year; }
        set { _year = value; }
    }

    //Make property
    public string Make
    {
        get { return _make; }
        set { _make = value; }
    }


    //Speed property 
    public int Speed
    {
        get { return _speed; }
        set { _speed = value; }
    }

    //accelerate the Speed property by increments of 5
    public void Accelerate()
    {
        _speed += 5;
    }


    //brake the speed by increments of 5
    public void Brake()
    {
        _speed -= 5;
    }

    }
```

This is my form so far

public partial class MainForm : Form
    {

```
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void getInput()
    {
        string year;
        string make;
        int speed = 0;



        year = yearTextBox.Text;
        make = makeTextBox.Text;

        Car myCar = new Car(year, make);
        speedLabel.Text = myCar.Speed.ToString();



    }

    private void accelerateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        getInput();
        myCar.Speed(); //error is here myCar does not exist in current context

        speedLabel.Text = myCar.Speed.ToString();




    }

    private void brakeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        getInput();
        myCar.Brake();  //error is here "myCar does not exist in current context

        speedLabel.Text = myCar.Brake.ToString();

    }
}
```

Comment: You'll have to learn about Scope. Your myCar Object is only available inside the GetInput() Method. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r0gHnBccxDI

Comment: thanks for that. I know about scope but wasn't sure how to handle it while accepting parameters

Answer (score 1):

you need to declare Car variable at class level

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
Car mycar;
private void getInput()
    {
        string year;
        string make;
        int speed = 0;



        year = yearTextBox.Text;
        make = makeTextBox.Text;

        myCar = new Car(year, make);
        speedLabel.Text = myCar.Speed.ToString();



    }
}
```

Now you can use mycar instance in all your methods

Answer (score 0):

Please find updated code of your original code.

```
 public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

Car myCar;

private void getInput()
{
    string year;
    string make;

    year = yearTextBox.Text;
    make = makeTextBox.Text;

    myCar = new Car(year, make);
    speedLabel.Text = myCar.Speed.ToString();
}

private void accelerateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    getInput();
    myCar.Accelerate(); 

}

private void brakeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    getInput();
    myCar.Brake(); 
}
```

}

Comment: okay I've made some changes to get those things fixed but now I'm getting an error that says:An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in L3A1.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: I made the corrections but when I run the code i'm getting this error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in L3A1.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  for the code private void accelerateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            getInput();
            myCar.Accelerate(5);

            speedLabel.Text = myCar.Speed.ToString();

        }    
Changed the class a little to this for both:  public void Accelerate(int speed)
        {
            _speed += speed;
        }

Comment: sorry it's garbled, not a lot of room for correction in comments

Comment: thanks a bunch guys but it's stil not working.  Getting errors at runtime that says  Object reference not set to an instance of an object. for the code private void accelerateButton_  I must have something funky in my class set up.  I'll play with it some more.

Comment: What's happening is that since Car myCar; is declared at class level so all the methods can read it we are not able to pass in the parameters needed for the class constructor, which leaves me where I was at in the beginning.

Comment: GOT IT I created an overload constructor and it fixed it all